# View the web.config used in the farm

Tags: 2013, workflow, iis, web-config

I recently faced an issue with the workflows of SharePoint 2013 on premises(2 WFE and 1 App Server). They have stopped working and the problem is a .NET security update. Microsoft has a script for this but I want to **manually** update all the web.config files as I cannot keep a backup before running the script. Please, could you assist me in the following questions:

1. How to find all the web.config files that are used by the farm?
2. Besides the WFE servers, should I also update the web.config in the App Server
3. After the operation, is an iisreset necessary?
4. Do you recommend running the script instead of updating manually?

This is the link to the issue and the script:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All web.config locations:

   - `\\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Port_Number` — The web.config
     file that defines configuration settings for a SharePoint content Web
     application.
   - `\\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Port_Number_of_Central_Administration` - 
     The web.config file that defines configuration settings for the
     SharePoint Central Administration application.
   - `\\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Port_Number\wpresources` —
     The web.config file used in the Web application's Web Part resources.
   - `\\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\wpresources` — A web.config file that is used in Web Part
     resources for the global assembly cache.

     > **Important**
     >   The web.config files in the \wpresources folders should not be    modified. The settings of these files disallow pages or items that can be compiled. If these settings are changed, the security state for the compiled code differs greatly from the security state for code that runs from the Local_Drive:\Inetpub\wwwroot directory.
   - `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\CONFIG` — The web.config file and other .config files
     that together define configuration settings for extending other Web
     applications.
   - `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI` — The web.config file that defines configuration
     settings for the /_vti_bin virtual directory.
   - `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS` — The web.config file that defines
     configuration settings for the /_layouts virtual directory.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms460914(v%3Doffice.14)

2. According to your link only WFE web.configs need to be updated.

> The solution is to explicitly add the necessary types to all web
>   applications' web.config files.

3. No need. Web.config modifications cause app pool recycling.
4. EDIT: (per @Trevor advice) Run the script. It will persist changes to database.

Comment: Never modify web.configs by hand. Always use the `WebConfigModification` class, per the script. Manual web.config modifications will be lost if for any reason the Web Application is reprovisioned.

Comment: Thanks for specifying that. Eventually, I will run the script, but I guess I'll need to keep a backup of the web.config files before executing the script. So, how do I know what files is this script going to modify?